# Window.OneSignal showing 404 error when i am trying to use it with next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, onesignal

I am trying to implement OneSignal web push notifications with the next.js web app. I followed [this article](https://dev.to/devpato/push-notifications-in-reactjs-with-onesignal-5bon)

to implement it. But it is not implementing properly as it shows an error. I have doubt that where should I place the `window.OnseSignal` code shown in step 7.
**What I did?**
I built a component name `NewOneSignal` instead of pasting it in App.js (because there is no App.js file in next.js) whose code is given below:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const NewOneSignal=()=>{
useEffect(()=>{
  window.OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
  const OneSignal = window.OneSignal;
},[]);
return (
  OneSignal.push(()=> {
    OneSignal.init(
      {
        appId: "i pasted my app id here", //STEP 9
        promptOptions: {
          slidedown: {
            enabled: true,
            actionMessage: "We'd like to show you notifications for the latest Jobs and updates about the following categories.",
            acceptButtonText: "OMG YEEEEESS!",
            cancelButtonText: "NAHHH",
            categories: {
                tags: [
                    {
                        tag: "governmentJobs",
                        label: "Government Jobs",
                    },
                    {
                      tag: "PrivateJobs",
                      label: "Private Jobs",
                    }
                    
                ]
            }     
        } 
      },
      welcomeNotification: {
        "title": "The website",
        "message": "Thanks for subscribing!",
      } 
    },
      //Automatically subscribe to the new_app_version tag
      OneSignal.sendTag("new_app_version", "new_app_version", tagsSent => {
        // Callback called when tag has finished sending
        console.log('new_app_version TAG SENT', tagsSent);
      })
    );
  })
  
)
   
}

export default NewOneSignal;
```

And imported this component in the `document.js` file. According to this article, I have to put step 8 code in the `useEffect` but didn't work also, I have tried that also
I am very much sure that the problem is in this file. I paste the OneSignalsdk script in head section of the `_document.js` file.Also, i moved the two service worker files in a `public` folder as shown in the article. Please help me to make this code work

Comment: try putting all the code in `return` statement inside the `useEffect`

Comment: Nope,i dont think so.There must be a proper way to use OneSignal with next.js.why we use a hook inside return statement.